# Prove that $|X|$ and $\frac{X}{|X|}$ are independent random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a problem with following exercise. I am given $X$~$N(0,1)$. I need to prove that $S=|X|$ and $R=\frac{X}{|X|}$ are independent random variables. My idea was to calculate distribution for $S$,$R$  and see if its product is distribution of $(S,R)$.
$$P(|X|<t)=P(-t<X<t)=2\Phi(t)-1$$
Now for $R$ I have a problem.
$P(\frac{X}{|X|}<t)$, thoght about spliting it into $2$ cases:
$$1. X>0$$ Then we will have:
$$P(1<t)$$ So it's one for $t>1$ and zero otherwise.
$$2. X<0$$
$$P(\frac{X}{|X|}<t)=P(\frac{X}{-X}<t)=P(-1<t)$$ So one for $t>-1$ and zero otherwise. Is it correct? Now for $(S,R)$:
$$P(|X|<t,\frac{X}{|X|}<s)$$ So we split into cases once again for X greater than zero and less. 
$$$$
$P(X<t,1<s)$=$P(X<t)$ for $s>1$ and zero otherwise. 
Now we look at product of $S$ and $R$ $$P(X<t)P(1<s)=P(X<t)=P(X<t,1<s)$$ for $s>1$ and zero otherwise.Similarly for $X<0$. And from that I can conclude that S and R are in fact independent?

Comment: It is $P(|X|<t)=P(-t<X<t)=2\Phi(t)\color{red}{-1}$ // Please make an edit.

Comment: Thanks. Appart from that it's correct?

Comment: Only what I can say at the moment is that the distributions of $S$ and $R$ are correct.

Comment: Okey, thanks. I edited. From what I write we may conclude that they are independent?

Comment: Ask dhrab, he seems to be on the right track.

Comment: For any symmetric continuous distribution, sign and magnitude are independently distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essential is here that $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution and that $P(X=0)=0$.

Only for convenience (so it is not essential) we accept the extra condition $\{X=0\}=\varnothing$.

Observe that $R:=\frac{X}{|X|}$ only takes values in $\{-1,1\}$ and that $S:=|X|$ only takes values in $(0,\infty)$.

Proving independence can be done then by showing that $$P(S\in A\wedge R=1)=P(S\in A)P(R=1)$$ where $A$ denotes a measurable subset of $(0,\infty)$.

Now observe that:

- $P(|X|\in A\wedge X>0)=P(X\in A)$
- $P(|X|\in A)=P(X\in A)+P(-X\in A)=2P(X\in A)$
- $P(X>0)=\frac12$

So $P(|X|\in A\wedge X>0)=P(|X|\in A)P(X>0)$.

Observe that $\{X>0\}=\{R=1\}$ and of course $\{|X|\in A\}=\{S\in A\}$.

In the second bullet it is used that $X$ and $-X$ has the same distribution.

In the third bullet this is also used together with the fact that $P(X=0)=0$.